# Laravel - Change base URL globally?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Let assume, the base URL of my application is - `http://www.example.com` (I have not set anything in any config file to specify this). There are a lot of hard coded urls in the application.

```
eg. <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
```

Now, if I go though the application using an URL like - `http://www.example.com/country`, is it possible to assign a global base URL, where when I click on contact it will take me to - `http://www.example.com/country/contact`.

There are a lot of such hard-coded URL, changing it individually will take a lot of time (like appending it with a global variable). Is there any simpler way to do this or is there any config specific for this in laravel? I am fairly new to laravel. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Good IDE/editor + regex will do the job, otherwise server rewrite.

Comment: @Jarek - Yeah, I did consider the option. The application is so huge it involves a lot of changes in lot of files, plus I only recently got ownership to the app, I dont want to mess up any thing.

Comment: Lord praise the TESTED code! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the somewhat cumbersome solution of applying a filter, as suggested by @worldask, but I think it would be better to set a **[named route](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes)** and change all occurrences using a regular expression (any decent editor allows for that). That way, for the lifetime of your application you only need to change the routes in `routes.php`, and it will be reflected everywhere.

e.g

```
Route::get('country/contact', ['as'   => 'contact', 
                               'uses' => 'SomeController@someFn'];

 <a href="{{route('contact')}}">Contact</a>
```

Of course, the same principle applies to adding a prefixed group of routes, so you can wrap the entire routes file with a group prefixed by 'country'.

Comment: The change is application wide. So my question is - how do I change the app's base url in the config file? Which specific file and which specific property?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried :) It does not seem to work :P

Comment: Yeah, I guess I dont have any other option other than replacing all the href's manually.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `Route Prefixing`

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'country'), function(){
  Route::get('Contact', 'HomeController@index');
  Route::get('another', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

---

**edit** 
try route filter

```
Route::filter('filtername', function($route, $request, $value)
{
    if ($route == 'country') {
      return Redirect::to(url);
    }
});
```

Comment: That wont work. All the hard-coded URLs are in the view files. Routes will only work, if I explicitly go through the URL like - example.com/country/another. But that is not my problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I dont want to redirect it internally. I want explicit href's.